# Microsoft Graph API Subscription Create

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription

If I run a "create" request on an existing subscription will the subscription be updated with the new values?  Or will the subscription remain unchanged?

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
   "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send that POST to the `/subscriptions` endpoint, it will create a new subscription based on the provided data and `WILL NOT` update an existing subscription. Each time you send a POST request to create a subscription, a new subscription is created with a unique identifier.

If you want to update an existing subscription, you need to use the PATCH method and provide the specific subscription Id you want to update:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/{id}
```